# Saving state from child component by pressing a button in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

I've been working on a project that requires me to set a number from a child component, and then grab said number by pressing a button that is located in the parent component.

to make this even more difficult for myself, the child component is repeated multiple times, and the button on the parent component needs to grab the value of the state from each of the child components.

How can i go about doing this? I've coded up a quick example that shows my problem in a simple and basic way, i am really lost.

***[Example code on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-https-rwo7f?file=/src/components/Example.jsx)***

for the example code, i am trying to grab the random generated number from Random.jsx, and save it to the state of **ranNum1**, and **ranNum2** located in the parent component Example.jsx, the parent component has the button that needs to grab the data.

Parent Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import Random from "./Random";
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ranNum1: 0, ranNum2: 0 };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{this.state.title}</title>
        </Helmet>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="col s12" id="create-room-block">
            <h1 className="center-align" id="create-room-title">
              Grab Random Number
            </h1>
            <h5 className="center-align" id="create-room-desc">
              <b>
                Click the button to grab the 2 random generated number from the
                child components
              </b>
            </h5>
            <h5 className="center-align" id="create-room-desc">
              Catch is the button is located in the parent component
            </h5>{" "}
            <br />
            <Random stage="first" uid="num1" />
            <Random stage="second" uid="num2" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <hr />
            <br />
            <p className="center-align">
              <button
                className="btn"
                id="save-num-button"
                onClick={this.handleGrabNums}
              >
                Grab both random numbers
              </button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

child component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { randomNumber: 0 };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.generateNumber}>
          Generate {this.props.stage} random number
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  generateNumber = () => {
    const generatedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    this.setState({ randomNumber: generatedNumber });
    alert(this.state.randomNumber);
  };
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: Just a heads up your sandbox is broken. Need to remove the .js in your import in App.js

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is pass a function from the parent into the child as a prop. Then in the child you call the prop function.

What I have also done is a small edit to the Random Component prop where the uid now matches the name in state. So when the handleChange function gets called from the child, you pass in the number and the uid so you can easily change the state in the parent.

```js
// Parent Component
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ranNum1: 0, ranNum2: 0 };
  
    this.handleChange = (num, uid) => {
      this.state[uid] = num;
    };

    this.handleGrabNums = () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    };
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{this.state.title}</title>
        </Helmet>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="col s12" id="create-room-block">
            <h1 className="center-align" id="create-room-title">
              Grab Random Number
            </h1>
            <h5 className="center-align" id="create-room-desc">
              <b>
                Click the button to grab the 2 random generated number from the
                child components
              </b>
            </h5>
            <h5 className="center-align" id="create-room-desc">
              Catch is the button is located in the parent component
            </h5>{" "}
            <br />
            <Random
              stage="first"
              uid="ranNum1"
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <Random
              stage="second"
              uid="ranNum2"
              handleChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
            <br />
            <hr />
            <br />
            <p className="center-align">
              <button
                className="btn"
                id="save-num-button"
                onClick={this.handleGrabNums}
              >
                Grab both random numbers
              </button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


// Child Component
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { randomNumber: 0 };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.generateNumber}>
          Generate {this.props.stage} random number
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  generateNumber = () => {
    const generatedNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    this.setState({ randomNumber: generatedNumber });
    this.props.handleChange(generatedNumber, this.props.uid);
  };
}
```